# Solve using Riemann sums: $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

To solve this integral using Riemann sums: $$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x}dx$$ first we find $\Delta x_i=\frac{b-a}{n}$, and frome there we find $x_i=a+\frac{(b-a)i}{n}$. After plugging this into a formula, we get:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{a+\frac{(b-a)i}{n}}\right)\frac{b-a}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{b-a}{an+(b-a)i}\right)$$
But this is the part where i get stuck.

I've even tried separating this into two integrals so that we get:
$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x}dx=\int_{0}^{b}\frac{1}{x}dx-\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{x}dx$$, but then when i try solving it using the definition of Riemann sum, I get:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{n}{bi}\frac{b}{n})-\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{n}{ai}\frac{a}{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i})=0$$
Obviously this isn't the correct solution.

Using the Newton-Leibniz formula we find that the right answer should be $\ln a-\ln b$, but how to find that solution using Riemann sums?

Comment: At some level, you likely need to use the fact $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x) = \frac1x$.  Are you comfortable with using this?

Comment: A nice way to do it is to divide not arithmetically but geometrically.

Comment: @BrianMoehring the problem is solving a limit, you don't need differention, unless for L'hopital rule of course if needed. First though we need to get to the point where we can use it

Comment: @GEdgar I'm not sure what geomatrical division is.

Comment: @bb_823 There are other methods than L'Hopital that require knowing derivatives to find a limit.  My question still stands though -- are you comfortable with a solution that uses $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x) = \frac1x$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes

Comment: "Geometric division" is used in the FShrike answer.

Comment: @GEdgar oh I misunderstood, didn't think you were talking about division of the segment $[a,b]$.

Comment: @bb_823 Well it essentially is division of the segment $[a,b]$. It's partitioning it with intervals governed by powers ("geometric") rather than even divisions of $(b-a)/n$

Comment: @FShrike does this mean that $\Delta x_i$ rises exponentianaly as $i$ approaches $n$?

Comment: Just look at the partition I've used. It's not quite exponential growth. The $\Delta$s are $aq^j(q-1)$ so increase by a common ratio $q$ (geometric)

Comment: @BrianMoehring can you show me the solution $\frac{d}{dx}(lnx)=\frac{1}{x}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$When you try to "solve it using the definition of Riemann sums": for starters, the way in which Riemann defined his integral was a bit more general than simply looking at sums of $f(i/n)/n$.

Leaving that aside, there is a mistake in using the approach of $\int_0^b-\int_0^a$. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n}{ai}\cdot\frac{a}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}=\infty$$So you have calculated $\infty-\infty$ which is an indeterminate form. $\int_0^a\frac{1}{x}\d x$ does not exist, so you cannot make manipulations with it.

To the problem: the following approach is another example of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4305837/815585) technique.

Say $0<a<b$ are fixed. For any $n\in\Bbb N$ notice that $P_n:=\{aq^j:0\le j\le n\}$ where $q:=(b/a)^{1/n}$ forms a partition of $[a,b]$ and we can decide to *tag* this partition on the left, at every point $aq^j$ for $0\le j<n$. Then, "by definition of a Riemann sum/integral" (this is where the more general definition is useful!!), as we know $x\mapsto1/x$ is continuous hence integrable and the *mesh* of this partition $P_n$ is $aq^{n-1}(q-1)\to0$ which decays to zero as $n\to\infty$, we can say: $$\int_a^b\frac{1}{x}\d x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{aq^j}\right)(aq^{j+1}-aq^j)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(q-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(q-1)$$

To evaluate this limit, let's rewrite it as: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(b/a)^{1/n}-1}{1/n}$$

How to approach this depends on how you want to define the natural logarithm. But if you have a working definition, you can evaluate this limit as $\ln(b/a)$ quite easily and that is indeed the correct answer.

This might be slightly circular though, since it is common to define $\ln(y):=\int_1^y\frac{1}{x}\d x$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof involving the mean value theorem.

---

Using the mean value theorem, we can write
$$\ln(b) - \ln(a) = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\ln\left(a+\tfrac{(b-a)i}{n}\right)-\ln\left(a+\tfrac{(b-a)(i-1)}{n}\right)\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i}\cdot \frac{b-a}{n}$$
for some $x_i$ satisfying $a + \tfrac{(b-a)(i-1)}{n} < x_i < a+\tfrac{(b-a)i}{n}$ for each $i$.

Then using the mean value theorem again, there is some $y_i$ satisfying $x_i < y_i < a+\tfrac{(b-a)i}{n}$ such that
$$\left|\frac{1}{a+\tfrac{(b-a)i}{n}}-\frac{1}{x_i}\right| = \left|-\frac{1}{y_i^2}\left(a+\tfrac{(b-a)i}{n}-x_i\right)\right| \leq \frac{1}{a^2}\cdot \frac{b-a}n.$$

---

Then starting from where you've written,

$$\begin{align*}\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{a+\frac{(b-a)i}{n}}\right)\frac{b-a}{n} - (\ln(b)-\ln(a))\right| &= \left|\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{a+\tfrac{(b-a)i}{n}}-\frac{1}{x_i}\right)\frac{b-a}{n}\right| \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\left|\left(\frac{1}{a+\tfrac{(b-a)i}{n}}-\frac{1}{x_i}\right)\right|\frac{b-a}{n} \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a^2}\cdot \frac{b-a}{n} \cdot \frac{b-a}{n} \\ &= \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{(b-a)^2}{a^2}
\end{align*}$$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{(b-a)^2}{a^2} = 0$, it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{a+\frac{(b-a)i}{n}}\right)\frac{b-a}{n} - (\ln(b)-\ln(a))\right| = 0$$
and then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{a+\frac{(b-a)i}{n}}\right)\frac{b-a}{n} = \ln(b)-\ln(a).$$

Comment: For the record, all the other arguments I considered at least required Rolle's theorem to identify functions given their derivatives, at which point we're just a stone's throw away from the mean value theorem, and at which point I find this argument more pleasant than the others.  Whether this answer is a "cheat" or not may depend both on whether you think the mean value theorem for derivatives is too powerful and on whether you recognize this proof.

Comment: An interesting approach nontheless, but seems like from the start it's a lot easier to use "geometric" partition of $[a,b]$ rather than arithmetic one.

Comment: @bb_823 Definitely.  I will note that while ostensibly my argument uses the arithmetic partition, this argument can be made using any sequence of partitions you want for which the mesh tends to zero.  That is, you don't really have a solution using the geometric partition and another using the arithmetic partition; rather, you have a solution using the geometric partition and another which is independent of the partitioning method.  I don't know if there's an elementary method that is _actually_ based on the arithmetic partition.